# Как задать свои названия кнопок в Dialog (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx

Всем привет.
Искал аналог JOptionPane для JavaFX. Нашел класс Dialog. В целом он подходит. Но как задать в нем количество кнопок, например (Да, Нет, Отмена), да и вообще как поменять стандартные названия (Ok, Cancel) на свои, я к сожалению не нашел.

Код примерно такой:
`Dialog d = new TextInputDialog();
 d.setTitle("Титл диалога:");
 d.setHeaderText("Хедер диалога");
 d.setContentText("Контекст диалога:");
 d.showAndWait();`

Comment: вот тут смотрите: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/     Прокрутите вниз до `Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions`

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо!